# Cython cannot make exportable

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to create a Cython package, comprising of several files, but I cannot make them exportable.

Say, directory structure is the following:

```
packagename_src/
    - constants.pxd
    - constants.pyx
    - contract.pyx
    - orderbook.pyx
    - setup.py
```

File `setup.py`:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

package = Extension(
    name='packagename',
    sources=[
        'constants.pyx',
        'orderbook.pyx',
        'contract.pyx',
        'packagename.pyx',
    ],
)
setup(ext_modules=cythonize([package], language_level="3"))
```

file `orderbook.pyx`:

```py
from .constants import Side

cdef class OrderBook:
    cpdef set_order(self, side: Side, order: dict):
        ...
```

file `constants.pxd`:

```py
cpdef enum Side:
    BUY = 1
    SELL = 2
```

And so on.. As soon as the package name differs, I added a file `packagename.pyx` with explicit imports (example):

```py
cimport constants
from constants cimport Side
```

This is compiled eventually to the file `packagename.so`. However it fails on import:

```
  File "/some/path/testme.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packagename import Side
ImportError: cannot import name 'Side' from 'some.path.packagename' (/some/path/packagename.so)
```

Obviously I do something wrong, and exporting of the classes seems more difficult. Can anyone spot a mistake?